# ¿Como enviar ID o Código a ventana modal Bootstrap en Asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap, gridview

Amigos me podrían orientar en como seleccionar mediante un Linkbutton la fila de un Gridview y me abra una ventana modal(Bootstrap) y me lleve a esa modal ese ID(de esa fila seleccionada).En resumen, quiero editar los datos de esa fila,pero en una ventana modal.La ventana modal me funciona,pero el proceso para llevar ese ID,no se como hacerlo.

Este es mi código en al .aspx con un Grdiview:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="603px" 
   autogeneratecolumns="False" >
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>    
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAction" runat="server" Text="Codigo"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Codigo")%>'
                CommandName="rowEdit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-info"    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ></asp:LinkButton>       
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Este es el codigo de mi ventana modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                Add New Metal Group</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codigo JQuery para abrir el modal:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function openModal() {
        $('[id*=myModal]').modal('show');
    }   
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que poner un `UpdatePanel` dentro de la modal, para poder actualizar los datos.
Y relacionar el evento con el `Trigger` del `UpdatePanel`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                Add New Metal Group</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDato" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
                </Triggers>
              </UpdatePanel>     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Luego la funcion que puede cargar los datos, y mostrarlos en la modal.

```
protected void rowEdit(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string codigo = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    lblDato.Text = "Demo texto";

}
```

Por ultimo el Javascript que has puesto no haria falta. Porque con `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` ya se te tendria que habrir la modal.